# What is the usage of には in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-に

What is the function of には in this sentence:

> 子供たちは密集して教師を取り囲み、みんなの眼が教師に向けられて、四方八方から口々に絶え間もなくしゃ べり立てていたが、**Ｋには子供たちの早口の言葉が全然聞き取れなかった**

It seems to me that は should be in place of には　here.